# Lisp macro evaluating expressions when I do not want it to

Tags: macros, lisp

I am trying to write a macro in lisp that returns the nth expression passed into it and only evaluates that expression.  For example:

```
(let ((n 2))
  (nth-expr n (/ 1 0) (+ 1 2) (/ 1 0)))
```

should return 3.  I am getting a divide by 0 error.  My macro definition is as follows:

```
(defmacro nth-expr (n &rest expressions)
  (let ((i (gensym))
        (expr (gensym)))
    `(do ((,i 1 (1+ ,i))
          (,expr ,expressions (cdr ,expr)))
         ((= ,i ,n) (car ,expr)))))
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

EDIT:

Thanks to @Vsevolod Dyomkin for helping me with the above part.  Now there is one more problem.  When I try to do

```
(let ((n 3) (x "win") (y "lose"))
  (nth-expr n (princ x) (princ x) (princ y) (princ x)))
```

I am getting the error `Error: Attempt to take the value of the unbound variable 'Y'`.

My updated code looks like this:

```
(defmacro nth-expr (n &rest expressions)
  (let ((i (gensym))
        (expr (gensym))
        (num (gensym)))
    `(let ((,num (eval ,n)))
       (do ((,i 1 (1+ ,i))
            (,expr ',expressions (cdr ,expr)))
           ((= ,i ,num) (eval (car ,expr)))))))
```

Comment: Why are you calling `eval` in a macro?

Comment: @leppie because if I don't, it returns (princ y) but I want that to be evaluated.

Comment: `Y` does not exist at that stage. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 5):

The main thing is to FIRST come up with the expansion.

What should the working code look like? The code that the macro usage would expand to?

Then you write the macro to create such code.

Make sure that you don't eval any of the supplied code in the macro.

A simple useful expansion target for your problem is a CASE form.

```
(case n
  (0 (do-this))
  (1 (do-that))
  (2 (do-something-else)))
```

Now it should be easy to write a macro which expands `(nth-expr n (/ 1 0) (+ 1 2) (/ 1 0))` into a CASE form...

Answer (score 4):

You do not need `eval` here, and no need in storing expressions in a list.

A proper implementation is following:

```
(defmacro nth-expr (n &rest expressions)
    `(case ,n
        ,@(loop for e in expressions
                for n from 1
                collect
                `((,n) ,e))))
```

Your example expands as:

```
(CASE N ((1) (/ 1 0)) ((2) (+ 1 2)) ((3) (/ 1 0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got to `qoute` `,expressions`, like this:

```
(defmacro nth-expr (n &rest expressions)
  (let ((i (gensym))
        (expr (gensym)))
    `(do ((,i 1 (1+ ,i))
          (,expr ',expressions (cdr ,expr)))
         ((= ,i ,n) (car ,expr)))))
```

Otherwise, what you'll get is this - the `expressions` list is inserted as is:

```
CL-USER> (let ((n 2))
           (macroexpand-1 '(nth-expr n (/ 1 0) (+ 1 2) (/ 1 0))))
(DO ((#:G864 1 (1+ #:G864))
     (#:G865 ((/ 1 0) (+ 1 2) (/ 1 0)) (CDR #:G865)))
    ((= #:G864 N) (CAR #:G865)))
```

Comment: Ah that's helpful. Then I imagine I'll have to throw in an `eval` in order to actually evaluate `(+ 1 2)` rather than just return `'(+ 1 2)`

Comment: I have asked a follow up question above. Do you think you could try to help out with that? Thanks.

Comment: I would say, that the easiest way to achieve your goal, i.e. to evaluate only the n-th expression, would be something like: `(defmacro nth-expr (n &body expressions) (nth n expressions))`

Answer (score 0):

The error in your second example is that `EVAL` cannot see your lexically-bound `N`, `X` and `Y` variables.

From the CLHS for `EVAL`:

> Evaluates *form* in the current *dynamic environment* and the *null lexical environment*.

It would work if you declared `X` and `Y` as special:

```
(let ((n 3) (x "win") (y "lose"))
  (declare (special x y))
  (nth-expr n (princ x) (princ x) (princ y) (princ x)))
```

but this is still not as good as the `CASE` solution suggested by [SK-logic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8323514/12048).